# Using Fancybox2 to Display Dialog over Galleria

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2, galleria

I am attempting to display a Fancybox 2 dialog over a full screen Galleria gallery. Here are the z-indexes I set:

```
.galleria-container notouch fullscreen {
    z-index: 10000;  /* default by component */
}

.fancybox-overlay {
    z-index:100001;
}
.fancybox-opened {
    z-index: 100030;
}
.fancybox-close {
    z-index: 100040;
}
```

I have played around with setting the width and height of the fancybox div to display but only get a display of about 20px and then it disappears. Is there a javascript API call that I missed? Thanks.

EDIT: here is the link - http://cdn1.doneupsalon.com/test.html.

Comment: what you are missing is hard to tell without a link (don't have a magic ball, sorry)

Comment: You're so right JFK! I updated my post with the link. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are missing : `.` ... a dot (YES, a dot ... three, actually ;)

You have this in your document :

```
<style type="text/css">
    fancybox-overlay {
        z-index:100001;
    }
    fancybox-opened {
        z-index:100030;
    }
    fancybox-close {
        z-index:100040;
    }
</style>
```

Your posted code is right but not your working code in your demo page.

Actually, if you set the `z-index` to the `.fancybox-overlay` selector it would be good enough.

Comment: AYFKM! Wow, thank you very much JFK. Like mine, I bet half of the answers listed on stack are really masked requests for sanity checks. And I had temporary insanity. All the best to you!